# ITextSharp saying File not found when published to My server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I am using ItextSharp and I am getting a new font for it by doing this

```
string  fontPath = Path.GetFullPath("C:\\BMSApplicationFiles\\Fonts\\FREE3OF9.TTF");
BaseFont barCodeBase = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontPath, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

That file is in that directory on both my dev machine and the server.
When i run this on my dev machine it works fine, when published to my server I get an error saying FREE3OF9.TTF is not found as a file or a resource.
I have double and triple checked that the file is in fact there on my server. My application has full trust on IIS. 
and IIS user has full access to this folder. And still I get this error. Very frustrating.
Any ideas??

This code is Not inside the Web Application but inside a DLL class library that the web application is referencing. Do I need to add any more special permissions or something?

Comment: Looks OK to me at a glance - are you sure you've checked the permissions of the correct user?

Comment: Yes I have looked at the permissions and verified the file is there about a hundred times. This is why I am so frustrated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your next step should be to confirm that what you think is happening is happening. If you are allowed to, download and install [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) which will allow you to log activity including which files are being attempted to be accessed and by which user account. Apply filters when monitoring of course, or else you'll end up seeing **all** the activity on the server...

If that only confirms that the correct file is being attempted to be read by expected user then maybe there's something up with the font. Try replacing the font file temporarily with another standard one (e.g. arial or something) and see what happens. (this is unlikely to help as it works on your dev machine, but might be worth a go)

Comment: I have installed process monitor. when i go through the action that shoud go get this font i see all the other files such as the .js files being accessed in process monitor, but there is no where that says anything about the font file. I did is search for the stem and if finds nothing. I replaced it with an other common font and still get a similar error for that font as well.

Comment: There are a bunch of Fast IO Disallowed and path not found results that correspond to the path to the controller that would get call the method that would access this font, but nothing pertaining to this file.

Comment: I, too, had this issue, and got similar results from 'process monitor' (Possibly because I haven't yet worked out how to use the tool correctly). Anyway, it is definitely a permissions issue, but I can't work out which account the iTextSharp code is running under, so cannot set up the permissions corectly. My solution for now, is to build the iTextSharp project, with the 'snk' reference commented out of the AssemblyInfo.cs file, causing the code to run under the same account as the rest of my code (i.e. an account that does has the correct permissions).

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have a security issue.

If you run IIS7 then check that IIS_IUSRS group has an access to the file (open file properties in explorer select Security tab etc).

If you run IIS6 then check that IUSR_MachineName account has an access to the file.

Comment: as mentioned in my original post,  I have checked and double checked all of this. Still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when I tried to get it working with IIS.  Within IIS, I had to add he file directory as a virtual drive.  That worked for me when I had a similar situation set up.  Hopefully it works for you, best of luck